# Inserted formula not doing anything

Tags: google-apps-script, formula

I have put this little script together to insert an if(vlookup) formula into a spreadsheet but even though it is running it isn't inserting anything into the spreadsheet. Can anyone suggest what I have missed off or overlooked please?

Or is there an easier way to do this with an array? I'm still fairly new so not sure how I would execute that successfully.

```
    function idSiteCoordinator(){

    var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var shLog = SS.getSheetByName("LOG");

//declare  how many rows to interrogate (to the last row)
    var lastRow = shLog.getLastRow();
    var startRow = 2;

      for (var i=startRow; i<lastRow+1; i++)

    {

        //Grab the values for LocationCodes
        var siteCo = shLog.getRange([i],[12]).getValue();

        //Enter formula
        if(siteCo = ""){
        siteCo.setFormula('=if(E'+[i]+'="08 - Maintenance Request System",LocationCodes!$E$33,vlookup(D'+[i]+',LocationCodes!$D$3:$E$32,2,false))');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot apply the method setFormula to the value, but to the range. Change this on your method:

```
    var siteCo = shLog.getRange([i],[12]);

    if(siteCo.getValue() == ""){
    siteCo.setFormula('=if(E'+[i]+'="08 - Maintenance Request System",LocationCodes!$E$33,vlookup(D'+[i]+',LocationCodes!$D$3:$E$32,2,false))');
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Rivero, that is throwing this error up: "ReferenceError: Function function getValue() {/* */} cannot be used as the left hand side of assignment or as an operand of ++ or -- operator"

Comment: Edited the solution, could you please try again?

Comment: That works great @Rivero. thanks for your assistance.